# Shutdown Cause -20 after dropping my MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, shutdown, touch-bar, damage

I dropped my MacBook Pro 13" 2019. The Touch Bar is not working. The computer is restarting after 3-5 minutes. `log show` reports the shutdown cause is -20.

What could be the problem and solution?

Comment: Shutdown causes with a negative number are hardware related.  You may have broken a connection somewhere on the PCB or on any of the connectors in your MacBook Pro.  Given that it suffered physical damage, you need to take it in for service.

Comment: @Allan, I'm pretty far away from a qualified service plus I have a technical degree in electronics. So I was about to open it and try to find something fixable, like a disconnected inner cable or maybe a broken path on a PCB. With this question I was aiming to someone helping me doing that. Where may I get some advice on the matter?

Comment: You can try Apple Diagnostics (hold D while booting) but the proper diagnostic tools are guarded by Apple